# Bootstrap navbar working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">|||</button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically the toggle does not work correctly

The home link comes up next to the brand rather than underneath it like it should

I have tried to find errors but have been unsuccessful

Any ideas

Comment: It works fine for me: http://www.bootply.com/4ZlUXF3Bko. Are you sure you have all assets in the right place?

Comment: for me it just brings up the home link right next to brand.

Comment: for you did it go underneath

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my browser Chrome. tried it  on safari and an ios simulator and it worked fine

Comment: No, if that is your exact code you have a broken <script> tag which most likely would mess up how it renders - If that's the case, Chrome is doing you a favor by choking on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the HTML for the brand and button elements with the "navbar-header" class.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mGNYfCowMeMHi2qL7HO4

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">|||</button>
  </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1> </body>
```

Comment: Nuts - I was 10 seconds too slow =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `navbar-header` section, so something like this should work better:

```
...
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
</div>
...
```

You may need to adjust things to prevent the next section wrapping onto a new line, but otherwise the toggle should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
```

jquery.min.js"

fix it

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a top-down menu bar, you should use the "sidebar-nav"  element heirarchy.

like so :

```
<div<div class="sidebar-nav">
            <div class="sidebar-brand">Brand</div>
            <div >Home</div>
</div>
```